# Cannot get BlueStacks to work with proxy and command line

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I am having a lot of problems getting this to work. [I am following this tutorial](https://www.51sec.org/2020/11/21/tips-and-tricks-to-run-android-emulator-bluestacks/).

[Some sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c) say you need to put quotes in the command line.

Here is what the command looks like. I set cmd.exe to run with admin privileges.  I cannot get it to work with quotes or without:

[image: Command Line - Screenshot]

Here is what the file manager looks like:

[image: File Manager - Screenshot]

The program exists and is running but I cannot get it to work via the command line.

I am using Windows 11.

Also, I have the proxy server I want to use. So can this be done with a single line command with the proxy server?

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/244883/44325

Comment: I do not have that command in the folder you listed. Try running this command to see what executable programs are in that folder. dir "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\*.exe"